Prove that $tr(A^4)=8q-2m+2\sum_{i=1}^{n=\vert V(G)\vert}\deg^2(v_i).$

Let $G$ be a graph with adjacency matrix $A$. Prove that $$tr(A^4)=8q-2m+2\sum_{i=1}^{n=\vert V(G)\vert}\deg^2(v_i),$$ where $q$ is the number of $4$-cycles in $G$ and $m$ is the number of edges in $G$.

There are three ways to get a closed walk of length $k=4$ from $v_i$ to $v_i$.
$(1)$: Closed walk of the form $(v_i,x,v_i,y,v_i)$, we have $\deg(v_i)$ choices for $x$ and $\deg(v_i)$ choices for $y$.
$(2)$: Closed walk of the form $(v_i,v_j,x,v_j,v_i)$, where $v_j\in N(v_i)$ and $x\in N(v_j)\backslash \{v_i\}$. The number of walks is $$\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}(\deg(v_j)-1).$$
$(3)$: Walks along $4$-cycles from $v_i$ and there are $2$ walks for each $v_i$ is contained in, say $q_i$.
Thus, $$A^4_{ii}=2q_i+\deg^2(v_i)+\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}(\deg(v_j)-1).$$
Therefore, \begin{align*}
 tr(A^4)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(2q_i+\deg^2(v_i)+\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}(\deg(v_j)-1)\right)\\ &=8q+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\deg^2(v_i)-\deg(v_i)+\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}\deg(v_j)\right)\\&=8q-2m+\sum_{i=1}^n\deg^2(v_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}\deg(v_j)
\end{align*}
I'm stuck here. How to prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n\deg^2(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}\deg(v_j)?$$
Thanks in advance.

You can exchange the two summations as follows:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{v_j\in N(v_i)}\deg(v_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{v_i\in N(v_j)}\deg(v_j) = \sum_{j=1}^n \deg^2(v_j).
$$

Wow, very nice!
